# Is there a way to add commands to the more actions in the source control in the side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible through a extension to add custom commands to this menu:

[image]

[The docs *crytpical* mention a few extensible menus but nothing about the git extras.](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#menus)

Is it possible to add a command to this menu? Is there a proposal to make this extensible...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the right place:

> The scm/title menu is located to the right of the SCM view title. The
> menu items in the navigation group will be inline, while all the
> others will be within the … dropdown menu.

- from [scm menu contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#menus)

This code in my package.json works for me as a test:

```json
 "contributes": {
  "menus": {
    "scm/title": [
      {
        "command": "find-and-transform.searchInFile",
        "when": "editorIsOpen && config.find-and-transform.enableContextMenus",
        "group": "4_search"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Replace with your values.  That same command should be contributed in the `commands` section like:

```json
"commands": [
   {
    "command": "find-and-transform.searchInFile",
    "title": "Search in this File",
    "category": "Find-Transform"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Actually the inbuilt git extension has a good demo of all the tabs: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/41b1406d3a86566043dc4b49e41aba2e81a8612f/extensions/git/package.json